# Immutable classes and memory in C++

Tags: c++, class, memory, memory-management, immutability

So, I'm getting deeper into C++ than I did in school as part of a personal project I'm working on. I'm a Java developer, so memory management is a little hard to get used to again, and now that I'm going out of my way to code a certain way, I have a quick question about immutable classes.

When I think about them as a concept, I of course compare them to Strings in Java. But now that I'm in C++, a reassignment operation can potentially create a memory leak (or at least, I think it can). So now if I do this:

```
  MyImmutableClass a ("blah");
  a = a.modifyInSomeWay();
```

where modifyInSomeWay returns a new instance of MyImmutableClass, I haven't called the deconstructor. Is there something I'm missing here that would prevent the first assignment of 'a' from sticking around in memory?

Comment: If you are thinking of the assignment as a Java-like assignment, you would need `a` to be a pointer. This is the assignment operator.

Comment: I agree with @Greg that an immutable object shouldn't even allow reassignment. But to answer your concerns, this all comes down to the assignment operator, and how it is overloaded for a given class. See this explanation on the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279616#3279616).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case you've described, the *assignment operator* of `MyImmutableClass` is called to copy the right hand side of the assignment to the left hand side (overwriting whatever was on the left hand side). If your class really is immutable, it won't even *have* an accessible assignment operator, and you will get a compile error.

If your object is mutable, and you *do* have a (correct) assignment operator, then there will be no memory leak because destructors for data on the left hand side will run as necessary to release memory. Writing a correct assignment operator can be tricky for some classes, though.

This concept of assigning directly to a (user-defined) object does not exist in Java, since over there everything is a reference.

Comment: Ah, I see now, it's been a while since my classes in C and I forgot about the difference between putting stuff on the heap vs. on the stack. If I were to instead use `MyImmutableClass* a = new MyImmutableClass("blah");`, and try to overwrite the _pointer_ later with a method that returned a pointer to a new object, would that trigger the same behaviour in the destructor?

Comment: @monitor: No, that would be a leak like you initially predicted.  There are a variety of smart pointers you can use to get safer semantics, like the `shared_ptr` FredOverflow mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

The style of sharing immutable value objects which is found in lots of places in Java does not work very well in C++ due to its value semantics. Saying "the object should be immutable, but assignment should still work" is a contradiction. You *could* use variables of type `shared_ptr<your_immutable_type>`, but that clutters up the code, and hence very few people do it in practice.